# How do I use gunzip and tar to extract my tar.gz file to the specific directory I want?

Tags: tar, gzip

When I run `gunzip -dc /path_to_tar.gz_file/zip1.tar.gz | tar xf -` in the directory where the `tar.gz` file is located, it extracts just fine.

How do I tell it to place the contents from the `tar.gz` file into a specific directory?

I tried this `gunzip -dc /path_to_tar.gz_file/zip1.tar.gz | tar xf /target_directory` with a `tar` error.

I should also note here that I am attempting to do this in a bash script and that I'm running Solaris 10.

Comment: you can change your current dir to dir where you want to extract the tar and run the extract command from there like `tar xf /path/to/t.tar.gz` and then change the path back to original dir

Comment: @g4ur4v How do I change the directory in the execution of the bash script? I thought that wasn't possible from my searching...

Comment: when you run a shell script ,its current working dir is the one from where it is triggered , you can use `cd` command in your shell script and run extract and then use `cd -` to come back to the original dir.

Comment: Or better use the `-C` switch as mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do a single `tar` command to extract the contents where you want:

```
tar -zxvf path_to_file -C output_directory
```

As explained in the `tar` [manpages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html):

> -C directory, --cd directory, --directory directory
>
> In c and r mode, this changes the directory before adding the
>   following files.  In x mode, change directories after opening the
>   archive but before extracting entries from the archive.

---

As you added that you are using [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0624/6j9vek5hv/index.html), I think you could try:

```
gunzip -dc path_to_file | tar xf - -C path_to_extract
```

Comment: I'm running Solaris 10 - when I run this I get `tar: z: unknown funciton modifier`

Comment: @DemiSheep Without the - before zxvf like in the other answer maybe? Also maybe indicate the version of tar you're using...

Comment: Without the `-` I get the same `tar: z: unknown function modifier` message. I don't know how to get the version of tar I'm using.

Comment: @illuminÉ: Solaris' standard tools are, ahem, very POSIX-compliant; it's possible that `z` (and `j`) are GNU extensions.

Comment: @DemiSheep: do you have a `gtar`? If I remember, that's sometimes a name unter which GNU tar is installed on Solaris boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you want?

```
tar xzvf file.tar.gz -C /target/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

On modern Linux you can use:

```
tar xzf /path/to/file.tar.gz -C /target/directory/
```

This is pretty much equivalent to:

```
(cd /target/directory/; gzip -cd /path/to/file.tar.gz|tar xf - )
```

If you are not on Linux check your man pages for the supported options of your tools.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out...

The `find` command can be used to execute any command upon each file it finds.

```
find . -name "*.tar" -execdir tar -vxf '{}' \; -delete
```

Recursively match file names (`find`) in the current directory (`.`) whose name matches regular expression (`-name`) anything ending with dot tar (`*.tar"`) (double quotes prevent bash from glob expansion of *.tar -- in my literal test, due to surrounding circumstances, I had to precede each quote by a backslash). Then, for every matching file, execute `tar` in the directory of the found file (`-execdir tar`) with verbosity (`-v`) and extract gathered files (`-x`) from the tarball file (`-f`) located by `find` (`'{}'`) (single quotes prevent shell interpretation of local file name) indicating end of parameter list to be passed to `tar` for every matching file (`\;`) (backslash prevents shell understanding of semi-colon) and then tell `find` to delete each matching file as indicated by a parameter passed to `find` (`-delete`).

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers here mention all the caveats of the default `tar` implementation in Solaris.  One such caveat is that it does not support compression by itself.  A plain extraction can be achieved through:

```
gzip -dc < /path/to/the.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

Further, if you created the archive by something like

> ```
> tar cvf - /path/to/directory | gzip -c > the.tar.gz
> ```

you will find that extracting this archive always overwrites the original files.  This is because Solaris `tar` does not strip leading `/` from archive entries upon extraction and has no means of stripping path components.  So if you want to be able to extract a *second* copy of the contents, you will have to create the archive with a slightly different command:

> ```
> tar cvf - -C /path/to/directory . | gzip -c > the.tar.gz
> ```

or

> ```
> (cd /path/to/directory && tar cvf - .) | gzip -c > the.tar.gz
> ```

In the Solaris implementation, the `-C` switch does not apply to extraction. Assuming the archive was created using one of these two methods or similar, a variant of this second form will allow extraction to an arbitrary location:

```
gzip -dc < the.tar.gz | (cd /path/to/extraction/point && tar xvf -)
```

---

If you have GNU `tar` installed (`/usr/sfw/bin/gtar`), it supports compression directly, as well as path-stripping.  In this case, the usual options such as

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gtar xvzf the.tar.gz
```

will suffice.

Comment: If you do get handed a tar archive with absolute pathnames, `pax -r -s,^/,,` is one way to remove the leading `/`.